# Mongoose throwing error while passing multiple host

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am stuck in this problem from 2 days

`url = 'mongodb://1.1.1.1:27017/test,2.2.2.2:27017';`

whenever i try to connect it mongoose throws an error

MongoError: database names cannot contain the character '.'

I even tried with `url = 'mongodb://1.1.1.1:27017/test,2.2.2.2:27017/test';`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass multiple connections in the URL, but the name of the database needs to be placed at the last.

From the Mongoose Documentation:

```js
const conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]', options);
```

For your example thus:

```
url = "mongodb://1.1.1.1:27017,2.2.2.2:27017/test"
```

One mongoose object can connect to only one database at a time, although it can have multiple connections to that same database.

Comment: Thanks a ton that worked. I was struggling for 2 days.